# Android горизонтальный LinearLayout не ставит элементы в ряд

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Создаю горизонтальный LinearLayout, который содержит EditText и кнопку. Кнопка должна быть минимально возможной ширины, а EditText должен занимать всё оставшееся пространство и быть в одну строчку высотой.
Примерно так:
[image: желаемое расположение элементов]

Я пишу такой код:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speak"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save_card" />
</LinearLayout>
```

И получаю такую картину:

[image: что получилось на самом деле]

Кнопка не видна вовсе, а высота EditText почему-то удвоилась.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы эти элементы выглядели как на первой картинке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кнопка должна занимать минимум места, поэтому установлен атрибут `layout_width="wrap_content"`. А чтобы оставшиеся место занял `EditText`, надо назначить ему ширину `0dp` и вес `1`. Он будет «размазан» на место, не занятое кнопкой.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speak"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save_card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Фотографии прилагаются:
[image: Пример правильной разметки]

Answer (score 2):

Можно используя `android:weightSum` и убрав у поля для ввода `match_parent` сделать такой макет:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_weight="18"
            android:hint="54544554"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Э5454554" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо не используя данные аттрибуты а только немного исправить ваш код:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="54544554"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Э5454554" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

будет так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с учетом того что вам нужно так как на картинке, то я бы советовал воспользоваться первым вариантом решения. Там нужно только немного изменить вес каждого элемента и будет похоже на вашу картинку :)